# How to prevent sniffing while using ssl pinning?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, sniffing

I have an android application which using SSL in Api calls. I found some solutions to reveal transactions such as SSL Unpinning:

https://github.com/ac-pm/SSLUnpinning_Xposed

and

https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit

and

https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

I need a secure method to keep my application safe.

**I think this is a critical problem for our applications not users!**

Comment: SSL pinning is a way to defense users against a certain form of attack (MITM) *by others*. If the user wishes to MITM themselves, there is nothing that you can do about it.